Data Cardinality is Ambiguous when running model.fit for a matrix factorization model
I'm making a recommender system using a matrix factorization model. Here is how I define the model:
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Add, Dense, Dot, Embedding, Reshape, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Permute

# Get the dimensions of the training matrix
n_customers, n_products = training_matrix.shape

# Embedding dimensionality
dim_embeddings = 39

# Input layer for products and customers
product_input = Input(shape=(n_products,), name='product_input')
customer_input = Input(shape=(n_customers,), name='customer_input')

# Embedding layer for products and customers
product_embedding = Embedding(n_products, dim_embeddings, name="product-Embedding")(product_input)
customer_embedding = Embedding(n_customers, dim_embeddings, name="customer-Embedding")(customer_input)

print(product_embedding.shape)
print(customer_embedding.shape)

# Dot product of embeddings
dot_product = Dot(axes=[2,2])([product_embedding, customer_embedding])

print(dot_product.shape)

dot_product = Permute((2, 1))(dot_product)

print(dot_product.shape)

# Bias terms for products and customers
product_bias = Embedding(n_products, 1, name="product-Bias")(product_input)
customer_bias = Embedding(n_customers, 1, name="customer-Bias")(customer_input)

print(product_bias.shape)
print(customer_bias.shape)

# Reshape product_bias for addition
product_bias = Reshape((1, n_products))(product_bias)

print(product_bias.shape)
print(customer_bias.shape)

# Add bias terms
dot_product_with_bias = dot_product + product_bias + customer_bias

Revenue = Flatten()(dot_product_with_bias)

print(Revenue.shape)

# Output layer
result = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', name='Activation')(Revenue)

print(result.shape)

# Define the model with inputs and output
model_mf = Model(inputs=[product_input, customer_input], outputs=result)

# Show model summary
model_mf.summary()


You can see all of the expected shapes of data in the model definition above.
Below is how I define x and y
# Extract x and y values
x_customers = np.arange(n_customers)
x_products = np.arange(n_products)

y_values = training_matrix.flatten()
y_values = np.array(y_values)
y_values = y_values.flatten()

print(x_customers.shape)
print(x_products.shape)
print(y_values.shape)

from the output the shapes are:
(1188,)
(16006,)
(19015128,)
I fit the model using this code:
# specify learning rate (or use the default)
opt_adam = Adam(learning_rate = 0.1)

# compile model
model_mf.compile(optimizer = opt_adam, loss = ['mse'], metrics = ['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])

# Fit the model
history_mf = model_mf.fit(x = [x_products, x_customers],
                                y = y_values,
                                batch_size = 500,
                                epochs = 20,
                                verbose = 0)

When I fit the model I get this error:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.'x' sizes: 16006, 1188
'y' sizes: 19015128
I defined the model to take those shapes as input and output in the shape of y. So why am I having data cardinality issues?
For reference the dimensions of the matrix I am tryin to reconstruct from embeddings is (1188, 16006) representing (unique_customer_id, unique_product_id). Where the values are the interactions.
